# How to prevent ElasticSearch from adding escape characters to a document when using Java Client

Tags: java, elasticsearch

ElasticSearch adds escape characters to document when using Java Client (8.11)

I have a database that delivers the following array structure:

`"["Texas", "Texas", "Sidebet City"]"`

When I try to insert this array into an ElasticSearch document like this:

```
        br.operations(op -> op
                .index(idx -> idx
                        .index(tableName)
                        .id(crawlingEntry.geturl_id())
                        .document(crawlingEntry)
                )
        );
```

I get the following (escaped) representation in my ElasticSearch index:

`"[\"Texas\", \"Texas\", \"Sidebet City\"]"`

How can I prevent the Client from escaping the parentheses (")?

**NB:** The String in the `crawlingEntry` object is displaying correctly withoug escape characters.

Answer (score 0):

adjust your crawlingEntry object:

```
public class CrawlingEntry {
    // 
    private List<String> yourArrayField;

    // 
}
```

when you set this field, do it with an actual list:

```
crawlingEntry.setYourArrayField(Arrays.asList("Texas", "Texas", "Sidebet City"));
```

Then, when you index this object in Elasticsearch, the Java client will serialize this list as a JSON array, and it will be stored in Elasticsearch as you expect:

```
{
  "yourArrayField": ["Texas", "Texas", "Sidebet City"]
}
```